# React - Generate input field via dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am new in React and I am confused, What I want is i have a drop down list with options as 1,2,3,4.... upto n. Suppose if I select on dropdown number 5 then dynamically 5 input fields should get generated. Also for each input field which is created. I should be manually able to remove them with a remove button.

I have created adding of input options but it is manual like we click on add button new option is added and when we click remove that particular option with index gets deleted. You can refer this link for code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        users: [{firstName: "", lastName: ""}]
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  addClick(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
        users: [...prevState.users, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }]
    }))
  }
  
  createUI(){
     return this.state.users.map((el, i) => (
       <div key={i}>
            <input placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" value={el.firstName ||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
          <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" value={el.lastName ||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
            <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}/>
       </div>          
     ))
  }
  
  handleChange(i, e) {
     const { name, value } = e.target;
     let users = [...this.state.users];
     users[i] = {...users[i], [name]: value};
     this.setState({ users });
  }
  
  removeClick(i){
     let users = [...this.state.users];
     users.splice(i, 1);
     this.setState({ users });
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.users));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.createUI()}        
          <input type='button' value='add more' onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/qL83cf2v/1/

But now I want generate it with dropdown, selecting the size of input options let say 5 so dynamically 5 options fields are created.

Can anybody guide me on it please.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I have added the code how i created it  manually but need suggestions for dropdown dynamic generation.

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this should help :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [1],
      options: 1,
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  addClick(){
    const newUsers = Array.from(Array(Number(this.state.options)), (_, i) => i);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      users: [...prevState.users, ...newUsers],
    }));
  };

  createUI() {
    return this.state.users.map((el, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <input
          placeholder="First Name"
          name="firstName"
          value={el.firstName || ""}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="Last Name"
          name="lastName"
          value={el.lastName || ""}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="remove"
          onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}
        />
      </div>
    ));
  }

  handleChange(i, e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let users = [...this.state.users];
    users[i] = { ...users[i], [name]: value };
    this.setState({ users });
  }

  removeClick(i) {
    let users = [...this.state.users];
    users.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ users });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.users));
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  handleInput = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ options: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {this.createUI()}
        <select defaultValue={this.state.options} onChange={this.handleInput}>
          {Array.from(Array(100), (_, i) => i + 1).map((opt) => (
            <option>{opt}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <input
          type="button"
          value="add more"
          onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one helps. Link Output keys with ur input fields.

```
 function App({data}){
   const [selectedField, setSelectedField] = useState('');
   const [output, setOutput] = useState({}); // u can add a default values of the keys in inital state

   useEffect(()=>{
     if(selectedField !== ''){
       const selectedData = data.filter(el=> name === el.name);
       if(selectedData){
         setOutput(selectedData);
       }
     }
   },[selectedField, data]);

   const onDataFieldRemove = (key) => {
     setOutput(prevState => {
       delete prevState[key]; // if u dont want unwanted data in ur database or use
       // prevState[key] = null; if u want to maintain ur default keys;
       return prevState;
     });
   }

   return (<div>... add ur input fields and remove button</div>)
 }
```